# Does my sr-only alternative seem correct to you?

Tags: css, accessibility, hide, screen-readers

`display:none` or `visibility:hidden` are not good ideas to hide a focusable element, because screen readers cannot see them.

This is the "traditional" way to hide an element from view but keep it accessible :

```
.sr-only {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I started to use my own like this for check boxes, radio buttons that I style with their labels :

```
[type=radio], [type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;    /* keeps it out of flow */
  opacity: 0;            /* makes it invisible */
  pointer-events: none;  /* being able to click the content below */
}
[type=radio] + label , [type=checkbox] + label {
  /* custom styling */
}
[type=radio]:checked + label , [type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  /* custom styling */
}
```

Do you see any big issue with that idea ?

**New proposal edit after investigations :**

```
.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.001;
  pointer-events: none;
}
/* OR */
.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.001;
  z-index: -999
}
```

For tests : https://jsfiddle.net/pLyo52f3/

Comment: The `sr-only` class, whether copied from bootstrap or some other location, has been tested extensively with various screen readers, browsers, and platforms (desktop and mobile).  I would caution against trying to create your own.  It might look redundant with so many CSS properties but when you factor in PC vs Mac vs Mobile and Chrome vs Firefox vs Safari and NVDA vs JAWS vs VoiceOver, it literally takes redundancy to cover every situation.

Comment: To that point, I believe some screen readers will ignore content that is set to `opacity: 0`—which is why Bootstrap doesn't include that in their `.sr-only` class.

Comment: So I made so researches and hidding an element from sight with `opacity:0.001` seems okay for all screen readers ;) Plus, `pointers-event:none` seems to forbid only click events but the element is still accessible with keyboard so that's okay for me.

Comment: There's plenty of potential pitfalls to this technique mentioned here: https://zellwk.com/blog/hide-content-accessibly/  You could try to mitigate all of these issues and test in a variety of screen-readers, browsers, etc. until you know it's good. Or, you could just use what's already been tested at great length and known to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the problem here is that you are applying `.sr-only` styling to style *focusable form elements*.  If you look at a library like Bootstrap, they have a [set of utility classes for focusable and non-focusable screen reader text](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/helpers/visually-hidden/).  You'll note that in their example they are applying the "focusable" variant to *anchor* text.

[Bootstrap indeed has custom styled radio buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/checks-radios/) and other form elements. *However,* you'll note that they are *not* extending or otherwise leveraging their screen reader text styling.  Instead, they are utilizing [`appearance: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) to remove platform-specific styles and allow for custom styling of the form element.  ***This*** is the idiomatic and accessible manner in which to achieve custom styled form elements.

[Slugolicious's comment is quite apt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795077/does-my-sr-only-alternative-seem-correct-to-you/comments#comment125155482_70795077). While you may not opt to leverage Bootstrap (or a similarly mature UI framework) directly, feel free to borrow liberally from them; they have spent years honing and iterating on this code to maximize consistency and accessibility across platforms. Spinning your own would likely be wasted effort.

Comment: Thank you for your relevant answer :) It was more a curiosity question. I prefer to stick to Wordpress or Bootstrap techniques but I wanted some opinions about the interoperability of my solution, and precisely why it might be a good solution or not, depending on browsers native rendering rules

Comment: @alexander, I appreciate the kudos.